# start Opc Ua server in docker container

Tags: c++, docker, opc-ua

i´m new at docker...

My problem is, i want to start my c++ app (opcua server) in a container.

I almost have it, but when the container is started optically nothing happens. Only an empty line is shown.

But as soon as I press "ctrl + c" (to shutdown the server) the server view / application appears.
But by pressing the "ctrl + c" combination, the server shuts down immediately.

Outside the container, the program runs perfectly.

Can this be due to an error in the Dockerfile or what am I doing wrong?

I start my container with: "docker run opcapp"

This is my dockerfile...

```
FROM alpine

RUN mkdir -p /OpcUa1

COPY . /OpcUa1

COPY libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libxml2.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/

COPY libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libm.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libz.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY liblzma.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

COPY libpthread.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

CMD /OpcUa1/opcua_lasersimulator/OpcUaForDocker
```

Comment: Copying around system libraries like this is kind of dangerous.  Can you use a tool like Alpine's `apk` to install what you need?  Is the server actually not starting, or is it just buffering up its log messages?  (Can you make network connections to it?)

Comment: @DavidMaze 
thx for the tip, but for "apk" I do not have enough rights on the Linux server.
No, I can not establish a network connection.

Comment: @gegner1111: You run `apk` in the container, not the host. And if you don't have the rights in the container either, then that's your answer. You need those same root rights for those `COPY` to `/lib/`.

Comment: @MSalters: 
in my opinion, this is not due to the missing right, because since I copied the libs I could start container without "missing libs" errors. And if I terminate the program with "ctrl + c" then yes the program is running briefly.

Comment: @gegner1111: So that means you can `RUN apk` too.

Comment: I got it ... my command was wrong. It was missing "-it".